# How to prevent overall scrollbar from appearing when using grid with and overflow

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, layout, material-ui

I have a react-redux app where I am using the material ui Grid component. The layout is something like

```
<div>
    <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={3}>  
            <Grid container direction="column" style={{padding:"2em"}}>
                // some stuff
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={9} style={{padding:"1em", overflow: "hidden"}}>
            <Grid container direction="row" style={{overflow:"auto", maxHeight:"40%"}}>
                {searchResultElements}
                {searchHint}
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</div>
```

`searchResultElements` has variable length. When the there are many elements, they go off the screen and a scrollbar appears next to the inner-most grid-container as expected. However, there is another scrollbar that appears over the whole page.

When I inspect the elements using Chrome's developer tools, I can see that the "invisible" elements of the list are accounting for the need for an outer scroll bar. See picture below.

In the picture, the green scroll bar is what I want, the grey one is the one I want to get rid of and the purple hatched things are the elements inside the grid container which accounts for the vertical space that the grey scroll bar wants to scroll through. It's only purple hatched when I hover over the element.

How can I prevent this from happening, so that I'm left with only the inner scrollbar?

[image: Green scroll bar is desired, grey one is not.]

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that you don't need anything below de bottom line of your layout, you can add this rules.

```css
/* Target the element where
   you want the scrollbar
   to be invisible */
body {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

At least it will hint you in a direction, you would be able to debug more clearly what is going on, if not solve the problem entirely.

If it works, you can then add or remove this attributes with JavaScript when needed.